# How to upload an object using presigned URL along with tags in s3 aws-sdk-ruby v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, aws-sdk-ruby

I am trying to upload an object using a presigned URL. But I want to upload the the object along with tags. What is the proper way to do it?

**Approach 1:**

I tried the following ruby code:

```
signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new
signer.presigned_url(:put_object, bucket: bucket_name, key: url, tagging: 'taggingName=tagValue')
```

But this is only uploading the object, but not adding tags.

**Approach 2:**

I tried to whitelist 'x-amz-tagging' header and tried to upload the file along with the header from client side.

Ruby code:

```
signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new
url = signer.presigned_url(:put_object, bucket: bucket_name, key: public_url, whitelist_headers: ['x-amz-tagging'])
```

Client Side code:

```
return $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: presigned_url,
      ignoreLoadingBar: true,
      data: file,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
        'x-amz-tagging': 'taggingName=tagValue'
      }
    })
```

But this is throwing me an error while uploading saying "x-amz-tagging" is not signed.

Am using aws-sdk-ruby v3 (Ror)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestParameters)

> The tag-set for the object. The tag-set must be encoded as URL Query parameters. (For example, "Key1=Value1")

And the error is seems to be saying the same thing

> "x-amz-tagging" is not signed.

So when you create the URL you need to provide what kind of tags with corresponding values.

```
    PUT /example-object HTTP/1.1
    Host: example-bucket.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com   
    Accept: */*   
    Authorization:authorization string   
    Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 21:58:13 GMT   
    x-amz-tagging: tag1=value1&tag2=value2

    [... bytes of object data]
```

Example 6th on the same documentation page.

Whatever tags you have provided while creating the signed url, you extract the same from url and pass them to **x-amz-tagging**

something like

```
     const tag = signS3URL.tag;
     ...
     const options = {
        url: signedUrl,
        path: fileUrl,
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": file.mimeType, "X-Amz-Tagging": tag }
    };
```

I am not too good with JS though.

Last but not least check your cloudtrail logs for errors for tagging the object.