# How can I add tags to an object when using presigned AWS S3 URLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm using @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner on a Node.js server to generate presigned URLs which my web application is then using to upload files to my S3 bucket. This works well, but I am struggling to add tags to the files.

Here is my current server side code:

```
    const putObjectCommandParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: fileKey,
      ContentType: contentType,
      Tagging: "org=abc&y=2021"
    };
  
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(putObjectCommandParams);
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
```

Here is my current web application code:

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', signedUploadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        alert('File uploaded successfully.');
        this.fileUploaded(fileName, presignedResponse.file);
      } else {
        alert('Could not upload file. Status: ' + xhr.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = (err) => {
      alert('Could not upload file. ' + err);
    };
    xhr.send(file);
```

The file uploads successfully and appears in S3, but the tags are blank when I check in the AWS console.

As some other answers suggest, I've tried to add the exact same tag string to an "X-Amz-Tagging" header in the file upload request, but then the upload fails and I then get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message>
<HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-tagging</HeadersNotSigned>
...
```

Does anyone know why this might be or can you see anything obvious I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: This might help  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702099/1273882

Comment: I've tried that answer but when I add an "X-Amz-Tagging" header to the file upload request from the client, I get the following error: <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message><HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-tagging</HeadersNotSigned>...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`x-amz-tagging` also needs to be signed & sent in the request header**, unlike other headers that can be a query string.

Taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/packages/s3-request-presigner/src/presigner.ts#L36), `@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner` will by default ['hoist'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) all headers - including `x-amz-tagging` - to the query parameters of the presigned URL. An exception is `x-amz-server-side-encryption` but `x-amz-tagging` should also be added.

As a result of the hoisting, S3 doesn't add the tags to the object.

---

With the current code, and its accompanying SDK implementation, you'll get something similar to:

```
https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx.xxx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=xxxx&X-Amz-Date=xxx&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=xxx
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&x-amz-tagging=org%3Dabc%26y%3D2021
&x-id=PutObject
```

Note that `x-amz-tagging` is not in the value for `X-Amz-SignedHeaders`.

Also, only adding it manually to the upload request won't work, as the original signing request didn't include the header to be signed. This is why S3 returns the '*There were headers present in the request which were not signed*' error. In other words, '*You're sending the `x-amz-tagging` header when **using** the URL but you didn't originally sign it when you **created** the URL*'.

---

There are 2 changes that need to be made:

| Change | Description | Why? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Configure `s3-request-presigner` to not hoist `x-amz-tagging`, when creating the URL. | To ensure it is a signed header for S3 as it is a prerequisite for S3 accepting any request with the `x-amz-tagging` header provided. |
| 2 | Send the same tag keys & values (`Tagging`) as the value for the `x-amz-tagging` header when using the URL (to upload). | To actually pass the tags to S3 to store against the object. |

---

Change 1 can be done by adding `x-amz-tagging` to the `unhoistableHeaders` field of the parameter object we pass to `getSingedUrl`:

```js
const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
    expiresIn: 3600,
    unhoistableHeaders: new Set(['x-amz-tagging']),
});
```

Your pre-signed URLs will then start to look like:

```
https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx.xxx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=xxxx&X-Amz-Date=xxx&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=xxx
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-tagging
&x-id=PutObject
```

Note that `x-amz-tagging` is now within the value for `X-Amz-SignedHeaders`, and that it is no longer sent as a query parameter via `&x-amz-tagging`.

---

Change 2 can be done by including the `x-amz-tagging` header when making the XHR request:

```js
const objectTags = 'org=abc&y=2021';

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', signedUploadUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-tagging', objectTags);
...
```

---

With these changes, the `x-amz-tagging` header will be signed in the URL & also included in the headers of the request, enabling S3 to add the tags to the object.

---

Here is a complete yet minimal working Node.js CLI app to demonstrate the above:

```js
// package.json

{
  "name": "aws-sdk-js-presigned-url-tagging",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.441.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.441.0"
  }
}

// main.js

const {
    S3Client,
    PutObjectCommand,
    GetObjectTaggingCommand
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const {getSignedUrl} = require('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner');
const {writeFile, readFile} = require('fs/promises');

const s3Client = new S3Client({region: 'eu-west-1'});

const bucketName = 'xxx';
const fileKey = 'xxx.xxx';
const contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
const objectTags = "org=abc&y=2021";

async function createLocalFile() {
    await writeFile(fileKey, 'abc', 'utf8');
    console.log('Local file created...');
}

async function createPresignedUrl() {
    const putObjectCommandParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileKey,
        ContentType: contentType,
        Tagging: objectTags,
    };

    const presignedUrlParams = {
        expiresIn: 3600,
        unhoistableHeaders: new Set(['x-amz-tagging']),
    };

    const putObjectCommand = new PutObjectCommand(putObjectCommandParams);
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, putObjectCommand, presignedUrlParams);
    console.log('Presigned URL:', signedUrl);

    return signedUrl;
}

async function uploadFile(signedUrl) {
    const fileData = await readFile(fileKey);

    await fetch(signedUrl, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: fileData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': contentType,
            'x-amz-tagging': objectTags
        },
    });

    console.log('File uploaded successfully...');
}

async function getObjectTags() {
    const getObjectTaggingCommandParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileKey
    };
    const command = new GetObjectTaggingCommand(getObjectTaggingCommandParams);
    const {TagSet} = await s3Client.send(command);

    console.log('Object tags after uploading object:', TagSet);
}

async function doStuff() {
    await createLocalFile();
    const signedUrl = await createPresignedUrl();
    await uploadFile(signedUrl);
    await getObjectTags();
}

doStuff();
```

Output:

```
Local file created...

Presigned URL: https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx.xxx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=xxx&X-Amz-Date=xxx&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=xxx&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-tagging&x-id=PutObject

File uploaded successfully...

Object tags after uploading object: [ { Key: 'org', Value: 'abc' }, { Key: 'y', Value: '2021' } ]
```

Comment: One of the best, well formatted, comprehensive answers I've ever read on my 10+ years on this site. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisGrant Wow, I'm flattered! My pleasure and glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a little bit of info to the Ermiya excellent answer. His changes work for me also but in 2 of my 3 scenarios. You will see that the 403 error you got could be misleading in some cases...

Case 1: Local stack

If you are doing all the above but working locally with the Lambda emulator as in my case, the identity that is used to forge the security token for this presigned URL is you active or default AWS CLI profil ID. So, if you are using an AWS account that is "AdministorAcces" level it will work not problem.

Case 2: Anonymous request from a SPA Web App calling a Lambda API

This were the solution didn't work for me. And it's all related to the role that is assign to the lambda that I used to return the presigned url. You have to known that the temporary access credential that will be used (call to AWS STS) to generate the security token (X-Amz-Security-Token) use the access level that is giving by the role to the lambda. In my case it had the bare minimum to write to the S3 bucket (S3WriteAccessPolicy in SAM jargon). This policy didn't include the s3:PutObjectTagging action required to effectively carry what the x-amz-tagging is asking for. So the result will be a 403 error with the same misleading error msg "403 SignatureDoesNotMatch". But in reality, the PUT request could not be executed because of the lack of access to tagging rights. So this is my last use case that put me on the right track.

Case 3: Authenticated request from a SPA Web App calling another Lambda API

So, this use case was also working correctly with the Ermiya solution but why since the only difference was that one of my app was anonymous and the other one was authenticated (using Cognito). But looking at my code, I realized that the lambda serving my authenticated users was at S3FullAccessPolicy level (that include the s3:PutObjectTagging action right) and the other one was a lot more restricted (since it's anonymous). To confirmed my suspicious, I added the required action for the tagging to my anonymous Lamdba permissions and "boom", it work right away!

So the take away of this trial and error is to also make sure that the process that request the presigned URL has the correct permissions (s3:PutObjectTagging) otherwise your're in for some hair pulling sessions!